# Reading require() error reason in web3.js client

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

Solidity version 0.4.22 introduced error reasons for require and revert (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22).

I tried using them, but it looks like they only work when I'm using the javascript VM on remix. When calling a function using web3 the error is a good old "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" without any extra info.

Am I missing something?

Comment: To my knowledge, those reason strings aren't persisted anywhere. They can be seen by debug trace, and I imagine tools like Etherscan will make them visible to end users.

Comment: I expected it to show up in the transaction receipt, but it's not, and since they are not persisted anywhere as you say, I'm not sure what they actually do

Comment: They're used for debugging purposes, and as I said, I would expect tools like Etherscan to display them to end users in the future.